# Multiple URL's in Google Analytics Goals Funnel Step

Tags: google, analytics, goals, regex

Have a landing page with 3 packages: 1 of the product, 3 of the product, 6 of the product, each option has their own checkout URL but all will have `/thank-you` in the URL once purchased.

So they all start on the same LP but there are 3 possible paths to the goal.

If I select Regular Expression what exactly would I put in the `Destination`? Just `/thank-you`?

And if you select regular expression, from what I understand you are supposed to use regex in the funnel steps as well.

Would it then be possible to use the or symbol: `|` to separate the 3 possible 2nd steps into funnel step number 2 field?

Something like: `/(redoxol-h2|redoxol-h2-3-bottle-bundle|redoxol-h2-6-bottle-bundle)`

I tried just add the 3 paths into 3 different steps but the data was all wrong. If I separate it into 3 different goals the data won't be accurate either.